# My tree recursion method doesn't work correctly

Tags: java, recursion

```
 public static boolean isMirror(TreeNode left, TreeNode right){
        if (left==null && right==null){
            return true;
        }
        if (left!=null && right!=null) {
            if (left.data == right.data) {
                return (isMirror(left.left, left.right) && isMirror(right.left, right.right));
            }

        }
        return false;

    }

    public static boolean isSymmetric(TreeNode root){
        if (root==null){
            return true;
        }
        return isMirror(root.left, root.right);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        TreeNode root=new TreeNode();
        TreeNode n1=new TreeNode();
        TreeNode n2=new TreeNode();
        TreeNode n3=new TreeNode();
        TreeNode n4=new TreeNode();

        root.left=n1;
        root.right=n2;
        n1.left=n3;
        n2.right=n4;


        root.data=3;
        n1.data=6;
        n2.data=6;
        n3.data=1;
        n4.data=1;
```

I expect to receive true but I receive false. I assume I have missed a point or two. How should I fix it?

Comment: I assume it should be `return isMirror(left.left, right.left) && isMirror(left.right, right.right);`.

Comment: Good time to start using a debugger.

Comment: why debug when you can come straigh to SO and have someone debug for you........?

Comment: @Tunaki this one even makes more sense to me `return (isMirror(left.left, right.left) && isMirror(left.right, right.left));` why should I select that one?

Comment: I don't know. What do you want to do?

Comment: @Mona the first call's 2nd arg should be right.right.

Comment: seeing if a tree is symmetric as the function name suggests!

Comment: @ShireResident thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to `Shire Resident` suggestion:

```
public static boolean isMirror(TreeNode left, TreeNode right){
        if (left==null && right==null){
            return true;
        }
        if (left!=null && right!=null) {
            if (left.data == right.data) {
                //return (isMirror(left.left, left.right) && isMirror(right.left, right.right));
                return (isMirror(left.left, right.right) && isMirror(left.right, right.left));
            }

        }
        return false;

    }
```